# How get string values from a custom ListView when its Item is clicked

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I have a custom ListView with list item layout as shown
[image]

this data is fetched from web service and set to ListView through BaseAdapter, here I provide code of getView() only

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View vi = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;

        if(convertView==null){    
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list_item, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.desc = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.desc);
            holder.day=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.day);
            holder.high=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.high);
            holder.low=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.low);

            vi.setTag( holder );
        }
        else
            holder=(ViewHolder)vi.getTag();

        if(arrayList.size()<=0)
        {
            holder.desc.setText("No Data");

        }
        else
        {
            /***** Get each Model object from Arraylist ********/
            tempValues=null;
            tempValues = ( Weather ) arrayList.get( position );

            /************  Set Model values in Holder elements ***********/


            holder.desc.setText(tempValues.getDesc());
            holder.day.setText("$ "+tempValues.getDay());
            holder.high.setText(tempValues.getHigh());
            holder.low.setText(tempValues.getLow());
            imageLoader.displayImage(arrayList.get(position).getThumbnail(), holder.image,
                    options, animationListener);                

        }
        return vi;
    }
```

Now the tricky part comes, I want to get Value of desc TextView of custom list item, I tried this way

```
private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener(){
    AdapterView.OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Weather weather= (Weather) weatherListView.getSelectedItem();
            Intent intent = new Intent(ListActivity.this, Detail.class);
            intent.putExtra(Detail.WEATHER_DESC, weather.getDesc());
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    };

    return onItemClickListener;
}
```

but at line

```
intent.putExtra(Detail.WEATHER_DESC, weather.getDesc());
```

I get error as

```
11-24 08:36:10.343 1460-1460/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-24 08:36:10.343 1460-1460/? E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-24 08:36:10.343 1460-1460/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.weatherservice.ListActivity.onItemClick(ListActivity.java:179)
11-24 08:36:10.343 1460-1460/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:292)
11-24 08:36:10.343 1460-1460/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1058)
11-24 08:36:10.343 1460-1460/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2514)
11-24 08:36:10.343 1460-1460/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3168)
11-24 08:36:10.343 1460-1460/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
11-24 08:36:10.343 1460-1460/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-24 08:36:10.343 1460-1460/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-24 08:36:10.343 1460-1460/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
11-24 08:36:10.343 1460-1460/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-24 08:36:10.343 1460-1460/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-24 08:36:10.343 1460-1460/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
11-24 08:36:10.343 1460-1460/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
11-24 08:36:10.343 1460-1460/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have searched SO but no answer satisfies my requirement.

Answer (score 2):

```
    private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener(){
        AdapterView.OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                //Weather weather= (Weather) weatherListView.getSelectedItem(); // instead of this
                Intent intent = new Intent(ListActivity.this, Detail.class);
                Weather weather= (Weather) adapterView.getItem(i); // use this
                intent.putExtra(Detail.WEATHER_DESC, weather.getDesc());
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        };

        return onItemClickListener;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an `ArrayList` already and `onItemClick` of the `ListView` you are getting the position of the the item clicked, so you should do it like this.

```
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Weather weather= (Weather) arrayList.get(i); // i is the position of item clicked.
            Intent intent = new Intent(ListActivity.this, Detail.class);
            intent.putExtra(Detail.WEATHER_DESC, weather.getDesc());
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem come from your approach. I suggest you do it another way:

```
//create getWeather function in your adapter
public Weather getWeather(int position){
    // do something like: return arryList.get(position)
}
// In your activity, set OnItemCLickListener for your listview:
yourListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
         Weather weather = yourAdapter.getWeather(i);//use your adapter to get weather
        }
    });
```